# bad syntax trying to define a local inside a block

Tags: scheme, racket

So I have the following code block in Racket/Scheme:

```
(define (inc x)
  (local (define a 1)
    (+ x a)))
```

And when I try to run it or check syntax (in Dr. Racket) on it I get the following error:

```
define: bad syntax in: define
```

I know it's probably something really stupid, but what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need extra parentheses.

(define (inc x)
  (local ([define a 1])
    (+ x a)))

Comment: Thanks. A lot. :) Knew it had to be something really dumb and simple.